# Validation for any one field is necessary in Laravel 5.4 in API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have input parameter for verify OTP for account verification.

Input param : **user_email, user_phone** (any one is required) , otp

How I validate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`required_without`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without) should work.

It means that the field is required if the other field is not present. If have more than two fields and only one is required, use `required_without_all:foo,bar,...`

```
$rules = array(
    'user_email' => 'required_without:user_phone',
    'user_phone' => 'required_without:user_email',
);
```

Comment: This code is OK, but email validation not work and if I am adding email after required_without: user_phone|email so I have seen two messages and not work properly